# AVCaputeDeviceInput capture bluetooth input

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth

I know how to set the AVAudioSession to be able to read audio input from a bluetooth device. I accomplish this by the following code:

```
  NSError *error;
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:&error];

  [self.audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                   withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:nil];

  NSError *errorTwo;
  [self.audioSession  setActive:YES error:&errorTwo];
```

By setting the options to AVAudioSessionOptionAllowBlueTooth I am able set this up. However, I'm trying to get this to work with a video recorder and I'm struggling to get this to work.

I'll post what I have starting from the AVCaptureSession:

```
     self.captureSession = [AVCaptureSession new];

      NSError *error;
      [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:&error];


      self.captureSession.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = YES;
      self.captureSession.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = true;

      [self.audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                       withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:nil];

      NSError *errorTwo;
      [self.audioSession  setActive:YES error:&errorTwo];

     [self addAudioCapture];

      AVCaptureDevice *audioInputDevice = [self audioDevice];



    - (BOOL)addAudioCapture
    {
      AVCaptureDevice *audioInputDevice = [self audioDevice];

      DLog(@"AUDIO INPUT DEVICE: %@", [audioInputDevice description]);

      AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioIn = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:audioInputDevice error:nil];

      if ([self.captureSession canAddInput:audioIn])
      {
        [self.captureSession addInput:audioIn];
      }

      else
      {
        return NO;
      }

        self.audioOut = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];

        dispatch_queue_t audioCaptureQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Audio Capture Queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

        [self.audioOut setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:audioCaptureQueue];

        if ([self.captureSession canAddOutput:self.audioOut])
      {
            [self.captureSession addOutput:self.audioOut];
      }

      else
      {
        return NO;
      }

        self.audioConnection = [self.audioOut connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

      return YES;
    }

- (AVCaptureDevice *)audioDevice
{
  NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

  if ([devices count] > 0)
  {
    return [devices objectAtIndex:0];
  }

  return nil;
}
```

However, the problem I'm facing is the audioInputDevice is always the iPhone microphone. I've confirmed that my bluetooth device is paired with my phone and I've written a separate application to test what input / output I'm currently using and I can confirm the the bluetooth device is readable by the iPhone. However, in the main app I'm working in I'm unable to set this. Any tips or advice on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this fixed? I'm trying to do the same

Comment: I am also having the same issue...